# Drag and Drop, making draggable false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I know this has been posted a million times but I don't really understand a lot of JQuery and can't get to apply the solutions I found from others questions to my problem, or even come out with my own solution. And since I'm desperate since this project determinates if I pass highschool or not I'm posting this everywhere I can.

I'm going to try to explain this as good as I can but keep in mind that english is not my native language so something may not make sense.

So, I have 3 images, one that is draggable and another 2 that aren't and, basically, when I drag the one image that can be dragged over one of the others 2, it replaces the target image with the new one, but then I can keep dragging that image and replace the other one, and I need that to not be possible.
Also I can't get the original div of the image dragged to desappear when the image is not there anymore.

Here is the Script I have

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData ("src", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault ();
 var src = document.getElementById (ev.dataTransfer.getData ("src"));
 var srcParent = src.parentNode;
 var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
 ev.currentTarget.replaceChild (src, tgt);
}
```

And this is an HTML example, not the real code im using since is really big.

```
<div style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="img/DraggableImg.png" class="img" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"/>
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="img/NotDraggableImg1.png" class="img"/>
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="img/NotDraggableImg2.png" class="img"/>
</div>
```

Another thing to notice is that once I drag the image the second time I cannot drag it back, not really important.

Well thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the newest [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/5/).

Steps:

I took your `HTML` and copied into the top of the newest fiddle.

I added a '`holder`' div around the draggable, just so you can see it.

All of the in-line commands and styling were removed and styling was placed in CSS (You can easily make changes in styling just by looking at the '`class`' of the element, going to the CSS side, and changing one or more of the lines to your liking).

The two 'dropme' images were not placed as images in the div, but rather as '`background`' to the div, and sized with `background-size`.

The JS was not even touched.

**Now, explanation of the jQuery:**

First three lines:

The .dragme element is made draggable by putting it into the selector portion of the jQuery .draggable command.

The `.draggable` command was modified with helper: clone which clones the `.draggable` element as it is being dragged - the original element is NOT being dragged.

Second set of lines:

The `.dropme1` element is made droppable by making it a selector for the droppable command.

The `.droppable` command was modified with `drop:` which will run the function after it when something is dropped on the droppable element.

The function has two lines:

The first line just appends the draggable element to the droppable element.

The second line add the class `.doneme` to the draggable element so it can have the same styling when I remove the class `.dragme` from it in the next segment of the chain. If the `.dragme` class is removed, the element is no longer draggable.

The third set of commands is exactly the same as the second set, just with different identifiers.

**Editorial:**
jQuery has a steep learning curve, but once you play with it a while you'll learn the basics of writing almost any jQuery command:

```
$('yourselector').jquery command( something and/or function(){});
```

and the stuff that is 'something' or 'function' has a reasonably clear structure once you study the documentation - you should spend a lot of time doing a whole series of jQuery experiments using jsfiddle.

**Here is a "complex" pseudocode of a typical jQuery command:**

```
$('.yourclassselector').yourjquerycommand('something', function(e, u){
                                                width: 100,
                                                height: 100,
                                                waistcircumference: 44,
                                                priceofm&ms: 6.0,
                                                costofOracle: 3000000,
                                                thendothis: function(e,m){
                                                                          alert('yoyo');
                                                                          }
                                                                      })
                                                                        .done(function(){
                                                                                         alert('I'm gone');
                                                                                         });
                                                                       });
```

JS

```
$('.dragme').draggable({
                        helper: 'clone'
                        });

$('.dropme1').droppable({
    drop: function(){ 
                     $('.dropme1').append( $('.dragme') );
                     $('.dragme').addClass('doneme').removeClass('dragme');
                     }
                         });
$('.dropme2').droppable({
    drop: function(){ 
                     $('.dropme2').append( $('.dragme') );
                     $('.dragme').addClass('doneme').removeClass('dragme');        
                     }
                         });
```